# M-< and M-> don't appear to work

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-layout

I am running emacs on Windows. I've been using the right alt key as my meta key for just about everything and it works except for `M-<` and `M->`

When I attempt `M-<` I get a message in the mini-buffer that says "Marker stack is empty"

`M->` seems to initiate a prompt of some kind for a tags related command "Visit tags table (default TAGS):" and I then have to C-g out of that.

I feel like I'm missing something really simple but I haven't turned up anything on here or google based on the results I'm getting.

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know the actual issue but those are the commands normally bound to `M-,` and `M-.`... are you pressing shift?

Comment: Oh my god....I'm an idiot. *sigh*

Comment: In a situation like this you can use `C-h k` (`describe-key`) to find out what key sequence Emacs sees when you type something, and what function that key sequence invokes.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've started using emacs fairly recently and I like it a lot. I feel like I'm finally becoming productive with it and this was the only thing that is really useful that I just couldn't figure out why it wasn't working. Duh.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like either something has bound those keys to some other commands, or else emacs is actually seeing something other the M-< and M-> when you press the keys on your keyboard.  To find out which, try C-h k (ie, `describe-key'), then press the combination you think is M-<.

On an emacs that's working normally, you'd see:

> M-< runs the command beginning-of-buffer, which is an interactive
>   compiled Lisp function in `simple.el'.

I suspect you'll see either:

- emacs thinks you've typed something other than M-<.  In which case, look for other things in the OS or other plugins that might be trying to handle hotkeys or do other clever things between the keyboard and emacs
- M-< is simply bound to a different function for you.  In which case take a look at your emacs configuration to hunt down what is re-assigning those keys.

Either way you should have a good hint as to what the problem is.

Comment: I marked this as correct because it summed up the info that I would have used to determine the problem; had I not realized I was not pressing shift this entire time..... It's been a long week. Thanks!