# How to debug lack of response to a certain set of keystrokes?

Tags: key-bindings, debugging

Suppose I do a certain keystroke sequence in emacs, and nothing happens, even though I expect there to be a keybinding that would do something. This could be because:

- The keybinding is not actually present.
- The keybinding is invoking the command, but for some reason the command isn't having the expected effect.

How can I tell which of these it is? (The specific example is that I'm doing meta-q, which is supposed to be bound to the command fill-paragraph, but nothing seems to happen.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [M-< and M-> don't appear to work](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/22389/m-and-m-dont-appear-to-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can determine which command a keybinding calls with `C-h k` then the keybinding.

In your example, you would enter `C-h k M-q`, which will tell you that `M-q` runs `fill-paragraph` (or at least it does by default in most modes).  If there's no command associated with the keybinding, Emacs will tell you so in the echo area.

Answer (score 2):

You can try using (view-lossage) (bound to C-h l by default) to see if your terminal even recognizes keystrokes. Some terminals might have problems with certain keystrokes. This shouldn't be an issue if you're using a graphical display for emacs, but your window manager might grab some key combinations, and Emacs won't even know about them.